# NewSingleHostReverseProxy is 10 times slower

Tags: go

I have this very simple RP demo [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Dq-HQj84ol) which looks like to be slower than it should be.

Here is an `ab` result made on the RP,

```
ab -q -k -n 20000 -c 100 http://localhost:8080/home
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1748469 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient).....done


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /home
Document Length:        0 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   4.842 seconds
Complete requests:      20000
Failed requests:        0
Keep-Alive requests:    0
Total transferred:      4360000 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    4130.48 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       24.210 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.242 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          879.34 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   0.9      0      10
Processing:     1   24   9.5     22      90
Waiting:        1   23   9.4     22      90
Total:          1   24   9.5     23      90
WARNING: The median and mean for the initial connection time are not within a normal deviation
        These results are probably not that reliable.

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     23
  66%     26
  75%     29
  80%     31
  90%     36
  95%     42
  98%     49
  99%     54
 100%     90 (longest request)
```

When i performance test the backend it can do 40k qps.

I feel like the RP could be way faster, but i m not sure how nor why it is showing the current results.

Thanks!

Comment: Stop using `ab`. It's still `http/1.0`, and not fast enough to give meaningful results with a server setup like this (not that a "hello world" http server is meaningful to test anyway).

Comment: can you recommend any suitable alternative ? thanks

Comment: `wrk` is usually adequate, but it still doesn't do constant rate requests which is needed to prevent the "coordinated commission problem". I've seen some new ones with constant rate features, [vegeta](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta) and [hey  (nee boom)](https://github.com/rakyll/hey), but can't comment on their usefulness yet.

Comment: @mh-cbon: Sorry, I didn't scroll enough to see the `MaxIdleConnsPerHost`. You can profile the code, but this might just be from the fact that a full http reverse proxy has a lot more to do than a server just writing out a small static response.

Comment: @JimB, no problem, i m grateful you helped. Its just the drop seems much stronger than i would expect. I think i m misdoing something, but i m not clear what.